# Array of different datatypes and operators in php

Tags: php, arrays

**Hi,**
i have a problem to solve. i tired but not get the result good result
please ignore if i make a mistake in question.

**Here is problem**

[image: Problem]

***My Approch***

```
$nwe = ["5","2","C","D","+"];
$test = 0;
$last =[];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($nwe); $i++) {
    $last[] .= $nwe[$i];
    $end = end($last);
    if($end === "C"){
        $t = prev($last);
        $b = array_reverse(array_keys($nwe,$t));
        if (( array_search($end, $nwe)) !== false) {
            unset($nwe[$b[0]]);
            array_pop($nwe);
        }
    }
    if($end === "+"){
        $test += prev($last);
        $test += prev($last);
        $nwe[$i] = $test;
    }

    if($end === "D"){
        $t = 2;
        $t *= prev($last);
        $nwe[$i] = $t;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($last);
print_r($test);
print_r(array_sum($nwe));
echo "</pre>";
```

***My Result***

[image: Result]

***Help me to out from this.***

Comment: What's your question about this? Also, please don't share text content in screenshots

Comment: So your problem is [picture] your approach is some code and your result is [picture]? .. the solution is probably [picture] ... (please don't use picture's of code - it's really unhelpful)

Comment: The problem is in picture-1 and then you can see my approach and the result of my code in picture-2

Comment: This is probably better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com, unless you have a specific question.

Comment: @waterloomatt No, broken code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some test to see how good you know your PHP functions. You need a few to solve this the easy way:

`is_numeric()` and `(int)` for the numbers. ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php))

`array_pop()` to remove the last array entry. ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php))

`array_slice()` to retrieve the last two elements of the array. ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php))

`array_sum()` to get the total of all array numbers. ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php))

`end()` to get the last value of an array. ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php))

This is the above applied:

```
$nwe = ["5","-2","4","C","D","9","+","+","-"];
$result=[];

//LOOP the array
foreach($nwe as $v){
      // IS IT A NUMBER ? (add number)
    if(is_numeric($v)){
          // just shove the number in $result
        $result[]=(int)$v;
        continue;
        }
      //IS IT + ? (sum of last two)
    if($v==='+'){
          //get last TWO entries from $result. (returns an array)
        $last=array_slice($result,-2);
          //sum of $lasttwo
        $result[]=array_sum($last);
        continue;
        }
      //IS IT C ? (remove last)
    if($v==='C'){
          //remove the last entry from $result
        array_pop($result);
        continue;
        }
      //IS IT D ? (last * 2)
    if($v==='D'){
          //get last entry from $result
        $last=end($result);
        $result[]=$last*2;
        continue;
        }
    }
  //get the TOTAL
$total=array_sum($result);

echo implode(',  ',$result).' = '.$total;
```

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend you to spend some time just reading on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). It's amazing how many functions there are.